# Can't create symlink

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm trying to create the following symlink `ln -sv $LFS/tools /` but I keep getting this error message:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/tools': File exists
```

I'm having some trouble understanding this error message. Is it telling me that `$LFS/tools` exists? But that, I think, is to be expected. Is it telling me that there is another `tools` folder in `/`? I checked and there's none.
Fairly new to Linux and I'm sure that this is stupid question, but I have been trying to solve this for some days and no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`man` / `info` pages are your friend

try `man ln` and you'll notice the proper syntax

`ln -sv $LFS/tools/ <link_name>`

will create a symbolic link in the `cwd` current working directory to the path provided. The syntax is reverse from most CLI formats i.e. `scp <from> <to>` format

Naming the link `/` is not allowed and I don't think that's what you intended

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The command I used was taken from the lfs book and I used it as it was writen.

Comment: Vote up if this helped